# Bootstrap selectpicker not working with handlebars.js

Tags: handlebars.js

I am using templating engine `handlerbars.js` with Bootstrap. Bootstrap selectpicker is working fine in all layouts, but when I apply `handlerbars.js`, unfortunately it removes the selectpicker formatting.